How to remove the "extra space-like" at the end of a value of a text box?
I am new to Access VBA (currently using 2016) and I have here a listbox that displays names from a table. I already have an event that when an item is selected from the listbox, values of the selected will be displayed in the 3 textboxes so users can update it if there's a need to. However, there's this extra space-like in the 3rd textbox.
Data format of each column of the entry is just Short Text. First textbox only contains unique ID (no extra space-like appearing at the end), second textbox only contains one word (no extra space-like appearing at the end), third textbox contains 2-5 words (has space in between words which is fine but has extra space-like appearing at the end that made me really curious why it is there). It seems like it is copying the behavior from the table because I also noticed this extra space. If I edit the entry in the table, this space is not actually there the same goes when I try to edit it in the textbox. I don't have a problem editing entries whether in the table or in the textbox. I just want to fix it to avoid confusion for the other users as this is like making a behavior of the Insert key of the keyboard (this time in backwards). Like if they try to remove the letter "e" from the word, "Names" using backspace key the preceding letter "m" is the one removed.
Entry from the table that has extra space-like or imaginary space

Entry from the textbox that has extra space-like or imaginary space

Edit: Added code for saving records to table.
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "INSERT INTO PAAMList (AMEID, AMMSID, AMNAME) "
strSQL = strSQL & "VALUES ("
strSQL = strSQL & "'" & txtAMEmpID & "', "
strSQL = strSQL & "'" & txtAMMSID & "', "
strSQL = strSQL & "'" & txtAM & "'"
strSQL = strSQL & ") "

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

I manually typed entries (to a field that has 2-5 words [AMNAME]) in the table it seems like it is creating that non-existent space.
Any ideas? Greatly appreciated.

How is this data input? Access usually drops trailing spaces. Somehow getting some other non-printing character. Review https://www.reddit.com/r/MSAccess/comments/1bi2wjy/form_textboxes_have_unwanted_white_space/

@June7 thanks for the link I read it and we have the same issue. Will try to check it once I get back to pc as I am not home yet.

For better understanding, needs to see the code during saving the records. You can use Trim function at the time of saving the record.

Try using another font in Sample Field.

If the listbox data is imported into your table from an external source then odds are you have a Chr(0) in the last position. You can confirm this by copying and pasting the entire text value, including the additional character, between the double quotes of the following code in the Immediate window: x="":?asc(right(x,1)). If the result is zero then you will need to cleanse your data in the table and also make sure to do this during the import process (if there is one). The Reddit link posted by @June points to the same issue. Might not be Chr(0). Anything under Asc(31) is unprintable.

Like if they try to remove the letter "e" from the word, "Names" using backspace key the preceding letter "m" is the one removed. -- in my experience, this usually means that there is a TAB character Chr(9) in the string, either at the beginning or end. This mostly happens when data is copied from a table (e.g. on a web site).
